# Convert excel file to csv in synapse

Tags: excel, csv, azure-synapse, azure-data-factory

When converting an excel file to csv in synapse pipeline or dataflow, I need to put the values of certain cells in excel in an additional column.

I was able to convert an excel file to csv, but I can't figure out how to read the values in a particular cell and add them as a column.

What I would like to achieve is as follows.
[Excel sample file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1bSb.png)

I want to add "outlet_code" as a column in the "C2" cell of the Excel file.
[csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rlzpk.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can try the below logic:

1. 1st use a copy activity to copy the content of the Excel file from A1 to c2 into CSV (assuming the place of the code remains the same)

[image]

Excel Source dataset :
[image]

2. Leverage Lookup Activity to get the code value
   Lookup should map to the CSV file generated above

[image]

3. Create another Copy activity to actually copy your excel content into CSV with the current setting you have and a below logic to add an additional column :
   [Add additional column in copy activity using Azure Data Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72448997/add-additional-column-in-copy-activity-using-azure-data-factory)

[image]